# How to use BN Code with Paypal Express Recurring gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, paypal, express-checkout, recurring

I have integrated express checkout recurring payment for paypal using https://github.com/fnando/paypal-recurring gem in my rails3 project. Now I got request to add BN code which provided by paypal for referral program.

I checked gem again but not found any parameter to pass BN code.
Can anyone have idea how to pass BN code with given gem? There are 'reference' parameter but its not for BN as per I checked in detail.

I referred https://www.paypal-marketing.com/emarketing/partner/na/portal/integrate_bn_codes.html#ec
But not helped much.

Please give your inputs if anyone has idea with given gem.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot, I'm guessing it would go in your application config

```ruby
ActiveMerchant::Billing::PaypalGateway.application_id = "your BN here"
ActiveMerchant::Billing::PaypalExpressGateway.application_id = "your BN here also"
```

See more here:
https://github.com/activemerchant/active_merchant/issues/888#issuecomment-130787898